# How to have "constexpr and runtime" alias

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, compiler-optimization

Constexpr can be awsome and useful for compilation optimisation. For example...

```
strlen(char*)
```

Can be precompiled using....

```
constexpr inline size_t strlen_constexpr(char* baseChar) {
    return (
            ( baseChar[0] == 0 )
            ?(// if {
              0
              )// }
            :(// else {
              strlen_constexpr( baseChar+1 ) + 1 
              )// }
            );
}
```

Which gives it a runtime cost of *"0"* when optimised... But is more than 10+x slower on runtime

```
// Test results ran on a 2010 macbook air
--------- strlen ---------
Time took for 100,000 runs:1054us.
Avg Time took for 1 run: 0.01054us.
--------- strlen_constexpr ---------
Time took for 100,000 runs:19098us.
Avg Time took for 1 run: 0.19098us.
```

Are there any existing macro / template hack where a single unified function can be used instead. ie.

```
constexpr size_t strlen_smart(char* baseChar) {
    #if constexpr
    ... constexpr function
    #else its runtime
    ... runtime function
}
```

Or some overloading hack that would allow the following

```
constexpr size_t strlen_smart(char* baseChar) {
    ... constexpr function
}

inline size_t strlen_smart(char* baseChar) {
    ... runtime function
}
```

**Note:** This question applies to the concept in general. Of having 2 separate functions for runtime and constexpr instead of the example functions given.

**Disclaimer:** Setting the compiler to -O3 (optimization level) is more than enough to fix 99.9% of static char optimizations making all the examples above "pointless". But that's beside the point of this question, as it applies to other "examples", and not just `strlen`.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if a function is `constexpr` and `inline`, the passed argument is constant, and the function result is valid as a constant, the function may *still* execute at runtime if used in a context where a constant expression is not required. (Technically, it may also execute at runtime in contexts where a constant expression is required, but that's not something a useful compiler does.) You don't want the slow version to be called at run time, even if the argument is constant.

Comment: @hvd i removed "const" from the example to avoid confusion. Also yes it will still be up "to the compiler" to choose to optimise (when possible). However the point is to make sure the most efficient variant runs on runtime. While still benefiting compiler optimisation.

Comment: I understand, but that isn't my point. My point is merely to warn you that if you try anything that amounts to `is_constant(expr) ? strlen_const(expr) : strlen_runtime(expr)`, that won't prevent `strlen_const(expr)` from being called at runtime.

Comment: `baseChar+sizeof(char)` -- no, just no.

Comment: [Here's a document](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3583.pdf) of the C++ Standard Evolution Working Group discussing similar issues and proposing several approaches to solving it (by language extensions or changes). However, as far as I understand it, the relaxation of `constexpr` functions in C++1y should already reduce the problem significantly.

Comment: @hvd actually this may be the intent of my question also. To prevent the const variant from running on run time. While not fully a must (the compiler tends to be smarter then most people), having that would be a nice option.

Comment: @Yakk actually ++ incremental modifies the given argument. That churned out some problems with constexpr sadly.

Comment: @DyP : Page 15. Approach D: extending function overloading so both constexpr and non-constexpr functions... Gosh i wish for that now lol!... looks like hope is in sight, even if it may not be an answer (yet)

Comment: @pico.creator try `+1`.  There is next to no reason why you would `T* t; t+sizeof(T);`, as that increments `T*` by a number of `T`s equal to the binary size of `T`.

Comment: @Yakk actually i prefer sizeof(T) for clarity of the +1 intent. And that it will get optimized out anyway: Anyway i changed it to +1, and shifted sizeof(T) into comment. =) Any further would probably enter into a coding convention debate.

Comment: @pico.creator you do not understand: `T*t=blah; t += sizeof(T);` advances `t` by `sizeof(T)` *squared* bytes.  Pointer arithmetic already multiplies added values by `sizeof(T)`, doing it again yourself makes next to no sense.  In this particular case it works *only* because 1 times 1 is 1.

Comment: @yakk now that's embarrassing for me, your right, I completely forgot I was not dealing with void* pointer arithmetic, in which sizeof(T) is valid. Been coding too much void* recently ｍ（＿ ＿；)ｍ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know any generic way, but I know two specific cases where it is possible.

### Specific case of some compilers

Also gcc, and clang which copies all features of gcc, have a built-in function `__builtin_constant_p`. I am not sure whether gcc will correctly see argument to inline function as constant, but I fear you'd have to use it from a macro:

```
#define strlen_smart(s) \
    (__builtin_constant_p(s) && __builtin_constant_p(*s) ? \
        strlen_constexpr(s) : \
        strlen(s))
```

Might be of use. Note that I am testing both `s` and `*s` for constexpr, because pointer to static buffer *is* a compile time constant while it's length is *not*.

### Bonus: Specific case of literals (not an actual answer)

For the specific cast of `strlen` you can use the fact that string literals are *not* of type `const char *` but of type `const char[N]` that implicitly converts to `const char *`. But it also converts to `const char (&)[N]` as well while `const char *` does not.

So you can define:

```
template <size_t N>
constexpr size_t strlen_smart(const char (&array)[N])
```

(plus obviously `strlen_smart` on `const char *` forwards to `strlen`)

I've sometimes used function with this type of argument even in C++98 with definition corresponding to (I didn't try to overload `strlen` itself, but the overloads were so I could avoid calling it):

```
template <size_t N>
size_t strlen_smart(const char (&)[N]) { return N - 1; }
```

This has the problem that for

```
char buffer[10] = { 0 };

strlen_smart(buffer);
```

should say 0, but that optimized variant just says 9. The functions don't make sense to be called on buffers like that so I didn't care.

Comment: Wow, thats a neat trick. Wasn't looking for a "cstring" specific hack. (as the question was more towards a generic concept). But its something new i learnt =) As for the compiler specific case, we are just short of 1 for windows. And we can wrap the question close.

Comment: With GCC, your `strlen_smart` always calls `strlen` when not optimising, but then the compiler knows how to optimise `strlen`, so it can still replace it by a constant. When optimising, however, I see calls to `strlen_constexpr` at -O. At -O2 or -O3, those calls get inlined, but not replaced by a constant. Testcase: `int main() { return strlen_smart("Hello, world!"); }`. This is exactly what I warned about in the comments on the question.

Comment: With clang, by the way, I do see a constant when optimising, but I see a call to `strlen_constexpr` when not optimising.

Comment: @hvd i actually added a disclaimer for -O3 optimization. As i feel its beyond the scope of the question. Alternatively, Is there a better and simple example that is cannot be optimized by O3?

Comment: @pico.creator I don't understand your comment. My point isn't that the compiler already knows how to optimise `strlen`, if that's what you mean, I merely included that as a side node. For a fair comparison, just use `-fno-builtin-strlen`. My point is that this answer doesn't necessarily do what you asked for, and mostly just plain doesn't do what you asked for.

Comment: @hvd yes O3 optimizes string length, however the question is more on a method to overload constexpr with a run-time version. And yes the string/char related hack does not answer the question. However the "compiler specific" answer does. Though not fully.

Comment: @pico.creator No, with gcc at -O3, the string length doesn't get compiled to a constant, it gets compiled to a loop that actually scans the string at runtime.

Comment: @hvd oh, inline optimization. Does that still applies for static strings? And yes i agree strlen, might be a bad example for this Q. But i cant think of something else that illustrates it nicely.

Comment: @pico.creator Yep, even for static strings, unfortunately. Like I said, I used `return strlen_smart("Hello, world!");` as a testcase. It *can* be executed at compile-time, as seen by `switch (13) case strlen_smart("Hello, world!"): return 0;`, but unless it's used in a context where that's required, GCC doesn't try all that hard.

Comment: @hvd Seriously, lol, then that actually made the question more relevant. In which the constexpr can opportunistically gut it out. And use vanilla strlen in other cases. Does this apply to clang also? (I usually use clang)

Comment: @pico.creator "And use vanilla strlen in other cases" is the problem... You cannot tell just from the argument whether the `strlen_constexpr` will be evaluated at compile time, and because of that, you cannot make it switch to the default `strlen` for those other cases. clang does better (see my second comment here), for `"Hello, world!"`, it can find the result at compile time when optimising, but falls back to a runtime call to `strlen_constexpr` (*not* `strlen`) when not optimising.

Comment: @hvd Yup that is exactly the problem with vanilla constexpr. Hence the question to work around that, to ensure that the correct switch happens. (or at-least not the inefficient constexpr). As DyP commented, this is in discussion for the next standard. And as this answer state (first part), a non-ideal work around for it.