# Is there a __builtin_constant_p() for Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there some function like GCC's `__builtin_constant_p()` for Microsoft Visual Studio?  As I understand, the function returns non-zero if the argument is constant, like a string literal.

In the answer here ([How to have "constexpr and runtime" alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20901977/1045800)) is a nice use case of it.

**EDIT:**
My idea was instead of writing something like:

```
#include <string.h>
int foo() {
   return strlen("text");
}
```

I could write:

```
#include <string.h>
// template_strlen() would be a function that gets the length of a compile-time     const string via templates
#define STRLEN(a) (__builtin_constant_p(a) ? template_strlen(a) : strlen(a))
int foo() {
   return STRLEN("text");
}
```

(I guess that is about what was written in the linked question.) 
All I need for that is a variant of `__builtin_constant_p()`.

Comment: Lol, u beat me to the question. 1up. (context: i posted the referenced question)

Comment: None of the answers are of any use for something like deciding between two ways to do something with vector intrinsics.  (e.g. one that works well with immediate constants but worse or not at all with values that can't be encoded into shift / shuffle instructions or `_mm_set1_epi8()` vector constants).  I guess that means MSVC doesn't have anything like this.  Even clang's implementation is flaky (e.g. [clang-3.8 fails to propagate it after inlining](https://godbolt.org/g/rxcDCC)).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example about how to get compile-time detection of string length (which is not the answer to the initial question but to the second one)

Please notice however that most compiler already replace `strlen("bob")` by 3 in the very first optimization level, so I doubt it has any use in reality.

```
   template <typename T>
   struct StrLenHelper
   {
       static constexpr size_t len(T) { return 0; }
   };

   template <size_t sel>
   struct StrLenHelper<const char (&)[sel]>
   {
       static constexpr size_t len(const char (&a)[sel]) { return sel-1; }
   };


   template <>
   struct StrLenHelper<const char*>
   {
       static size_t len(const char * a) { return strlen(a); }
   };

   #define StrLen(X) StrLenHelper<decltype(X)>::len(X)
```

Proof that it works on a recent compiler:

```
template <size_t A> 
struct Test { enum T { value = A }; };

// Outputs "5 5 4" if your program is called "test"
int main(int a, char**b)
{
   printf("%u %u %u\n", Test<StrLen("bobby")>::value, StrLen("bobby"), StrLen(b[0])); 
   return 0;
}
```

Some strange coding practice will not trigger compile-time behaviour like in `constexpr const char * b = "bob";`, this will call the run-time version because the type, at the time of call is `const char*` (`constexpr` is not a modifier you can select upon in a template, or I don't know how)

Answer (score -5):

In Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 there is the _IS_LITERAL_TYPE macro which makes use of std::is_literal_type, which is documented at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_literal_type/.

The following is a relevant excerpt from the documentation of is_literal_type.

"""Trait class that identifies whether T is a literal type.

A literal type is a type that can qualify as constexpr."""

Perhaps this would suffice.

The following excerpt from the documentation for __builtin_constant_p leads me to believe it will.

"You can use the built-in function __builtin_constant_p to determine if a value is known to be constant at compile-time..."

To me the phrases "is a literal type," "constexpr," and "known to be constant at compile-time" have the same meaning. Perhaps I am mistaken.

Then again, I will be the first to admit that I am not certain.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Unfortunately, it doesn't help, since `is_literal_type` only says something about the **type**. E.g. `std::is_literal_type<const char*>::value` is `true`, but for my use it's all the difference if it's `strlen(some_const_ptr)` or `strlen("abc")`, even if both parameters are `const char*`.

Comment: Perhaps my constant_p function would work. In my tests it does tell the difference between a string constant and a dynamically allocated string.

Comment: But I need that information at compile time, thus it cannot help me.

Comment: @cxxl, I think you're mistaken. `strlen(some_const_ptr)` is const char*, but `strlen("abc")` is `const char&[4]`

Comment: @xryl669: thanks. does this change anything for my original question?

Comment: @cxxl: Yes, a bit, since it allows a solution (see my answer). However, this solution is of very little interest as most compiler already pre-compute the string length at compile time if they can do so and replace by the computed value (easy optimization).

Comment: This answer completely misses the point of `__builtin_constant_p`.  It's for something like `int foo(int a) { if(__builtin_constant_p(a)) { some pure C++ that the compiler groks; } else { asm("inc %0" : "+r"(a); } return a; }`  Even without inline asm, you might have two implementations: one that compiles to code that works well at run-time but doesn't optimize away completely for compile-time constants, and another that's simpler and *does* optimize away.

Comment: A literal type is one where `__builtin_constant_p(x)` *can* be true if `x` has that type.  e.g. it just means that you *can* use `constexpr` with that type, not that the type can only be used to hold compile-time constants.  e.g. `int` is a literal type, as the example you linked on cplusplus.com says.  I think you got confused talking about strings, since working out whether the pointed-to string is a compile-time constant is not exactly the same thing from working out whether an address is a compile-time constant.  (Addresses are usually link-time constants anyway, not compile-time...)

Answer (score -6):

If is_literal_type is not what you want, the following function might be of use. With it I was able to tell the difference between a char string that was defined as follows and one that was allocated on the heap.

```
LPCTSTR constString = _T("Hello World!");
```

My implementation of constant_p is as follows.

```
int constant_p(const void *p)
{
    static bool s_init = false;
    static ULONGLONG s_TextSegmentStartVirtualAddress = 0;
    static ULONGLONG s_TextSegmentEndVirtualAddress = 0;
    static ULONGLONG s_RDataSegmentStartVirtualAddress = 0;
    static ULONGLONG s_RDataSegmentEndVirtualAddress = 0;
    if (! s_init)
    {
        s_init = true;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders = ::ImageNtHeader(
            reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(::GetModuleHandle(NULL)));
        if (! pNtHeaders)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        ULONGLONG ImageBase = pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
        PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pNtHeaders + 1);
        for (WORD i = 0; i < pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i)
        {
            char *name = (char*)pSectionHeader->Name;
            if (0 == ::strcmp(name, ".text"))
            {
                s_TextSegmentStartVirtualAddress = ImageBase
                    + pSectionHeader->VirtualAddress;
                s_TextSegmentEndVirtualAddress = s_TextSegmentStartVirtualAddress
                    + pSectionHeader->SizeOfRawData;
            }
            else if (0 == ::strcmp(name, ".rdata"))
            {
                s_RDataSegmentStartVirtualAddress = ImageBase
                    + pSectionHeader->VirtualAddress;
                s_RDataSegmentEndVirtualAddress = s_RDataSegmentStartVirtualAddress
                    + pSectionHeader->SizeOfRawData;
            }
            pSectionHeader++;
        }
    }
    if (0 == s_TextSegmentStartVirtualAddress)
    {
        // Something went wrong. Give up.
        return 0;
    }
    ULONGLONG test = reinterpret_cast<ULONGLONG>(p);
    if (
        s_TextSegmentStartVirtualAddress <= test
        && test <= s_TextSegmentEndVirtualAddress
    )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (
         s_RDataSegmentStartVirtualAddress <= test
         && test <= s_RDataSegmentEndVirtualAddress
     )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note you need to include DbgHelp.h and link with DbgHelp.lib in order for this to work.

I hope one of my proposed solutions works for you. I would like to know.

Comment: This looks like a atomic head to kill a mosquito. Yes it probably work, but it's completely run-time based, not compile-time based.